# AttributeError: module 'twitch_chat_irc' has no attribute 'TwitchChatIRC'

Tags: python, twitch

Хочу сделать своего чат бота для Twitch с помощью Twitch Chat IRC - https://pypi.org/project/twitch-chat-irc/

Вот в чем проблема.
При попытке подключиться выдает ошибку

```
    connection = twitch_chat_irc.TwitchChatIRC(channel_name, os.getenv('token'))
AttributeError: module 'twitch_chat_irc' has no attribute 'TwitchChatIRC'
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Все, проблема решена. Было import twitch_chat_irc а надо from twitch_chat_irc import twitch_chat_irc

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, то оставьте под ним ответ и пометьте его как верный

Comment: @videxerion уже 10 часов прошло, добавлю я.

Answer (score 1):

По просьбам в комментариях добавил ответ.

---

Ваша проблема решается заменой строки:

```py
import twitch_chat_irc
```

на:

```py
from twitch_chat_irc import twitch_chat_irc
```